# This is a good news. This is good news

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-meaning

> This is a good news. 
>   This is good news.

Which one is correct? Clarify the difference

Comment: Which one do *you* think is correct… & why?

Comment: You might also hear- 'it's a good news day' but this is a different meaning.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The word "news" is singular, uncountable. So you can't say "a news," instead you would say:

> This is good news.

just as in "This is good water."

Comment: What about these sentences?  This is a news channel.  This is news channel.  Can't I use " a" here?

Comment: Of course, you can say a news channel as it is a channel broadcasting news.

Comment: Why are we using "a" here? May I know the best reason? Please

Comment: Why do you say "This is an apple"?

Comment: Because,here the apple begins with vowel sound.

Comment: This is good news.  Here, we don't use "a" because,  the word news is uncountable noun. Ok fine then.  Why do we say,  this is a news channel?

Comment: Because we are referring to "channel", not to "news". "News" functions as an adjective in that context. *This is a news channel. This is a sports channel. This is a weather channel.* (Here, you can have the remote back.)

Comment: user124234 -- You can count channels. If there's one, it's "a channel". The word "news" in "a news channel" isn't the noun (channel is). But in "this is good news", news is the noun, and it's not countable. You could say "this is a good piece of news" (pieces are countable).

Answer (score 12):

*News* itself is uncountable. Uncountable nouns don't take indefinite articles *a* and *an*; at least not **directly**. Let me explain.

So far, we understood that

> This is *a good news.

is ungrammatical, while the latter form isn't. What if you do need to specify a *one* about news? That's where [classifiers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classifier_(linguistics))<sup>1</sup> come into play.

> A classifier, sometimes called a counter word, is a word or morpheme that is used to accompany nouns and can be considered to "classify" the noun depending on the type of its referent. - [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classifier_(linguistics))

The classifier for *news*, *jewelry*, *meat*, *cake*<sup>2</sup> etc.  is *piece*:

> - Sam just heard this shocking piece of news about the epidemic from the bus radio.
> - Pfft, this job is a piece of cake for a tough guy like you!

Thus, if you want to make your first sentence grammatical, use *piece* along with the indefinite article *a*:

> This is a good *piece* of news.

---

<sub>1: **Warning**: [Do **not** mix classifiers with noun classes.](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/512/how-exactly-are-noun-classes-different-to-classifiers) Inhaling the mixture might result in body inflammation and is highly toxic.
 2: Also, a *slice* of cake.</sub>

Comment: Don't forget: _This is some good news._

Comment: Oh yes, @J.R. Also, *this is the good news.* I figured it might get a little off the question and make the answer unnecessarily long and TL;DR-worthy.